# Explanation for CCC 2022 S3 solution

Tags: c++

After completing this year's CCC, I went online to look for solutions for each question. When I looked up the solution to [S3 Good Samples](https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc22s3), I came across a great website describing the [solution](https://www.geekedu.org/blogs/2022-waterloo-ccc-senior-problem-solution).

**Question**

You are composing music for the Cool Clarinet Competition (CCC). You have been instructed to make a piece of music with exactly n notes. A note is represented as a positive integer, indicating the pitch of the note.

We call a non-empty sequence of consecutive notes in the piece a sample. We call two samples different if they start or end at a different position in the piece.

We call a sample good if no two notes in the sample have the same pitch.

The clarinet players are picky in two ways. First, they will not play any note with pitch higher than m. Second, they want a piece with exactly k good samples.

Can you construct a piece to satisfy the clarinet players?

**Full solution in C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using ll = long long;

ll min(ll a, ll b){return a > b ? b : a;}

void solve(){
    ll n,m,k; 
    cin>>n>>m>>k;
    vector<ll> ans; 
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
    {   
        ll rem = n-i-1;
        ll cur = min(k-rem, m);
        if(cur<=0) break;  
        ll val;
        if(cur > i)//Add distinctive number
        {   
            val=min(m,i+1);
            cur=val; 
        }
        else{ //Add non-distinctive number
            val=ans[i-cur]; 
        }
        ans.push_back(val);
        k = k - cur;
    }
    if(k==0 and (ll)ans.size()==n)
    {
        for(auto x: ans) cout<<x<<' '; 
        cout<<endl; 
    }
    else cout<<-1<<endl;
}

int main(void){
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

(n m k)

4 3 9

**Output**

1 2 3 1

**Explanation**

Possible good samples are:
(1), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)
(2), (2, 3), (2, 3, 1)
(3), (3, 1)
(1)
Total = 9 good samples

**Concept**

The concept is simple enough to understand, by finding the amount in which each distinctive and non-distinctive additional value increases the overall score of the list you can loop through n iterations and find the corresponding value for each index in order to match the k value (final score of the list).

However, looking at the code I am not sure how the program decides whether to put a distinctive or non-distinctive number in the list.

In the article the author only briefly stated:

> To find a number for the i'th index, we will make a decision whether we will select a distinct or non-distinct number by observing the remaining value of k

More specifically, I've narrowed it down to this particular line of code:

```
ll cur = min(k-rem, m);
```

The cur variable to my knowledge completes these tasks:

- Controls decision to put distinct/non-distinct numbers
- Contraints the values to m (max value for each index)
- Determines the value for non-distinctive numbers

If anyone has any idea how this bit of code works, or if they have any corrections to my understanding of the solution please let me know.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Please show a [mre] without relying on external links

Comment: Just added the question as well as an input/output example